# Build combinations without pair repetition

Tags: python, optimization, combinations, python-itertools

Given a dataset I want to build all combinations (still using `itertools.combinations`).
To reduce the number of combinations `n!/r!/(n-r)!` I want to omit pairs included in other combinations.

For illustration a small example. All `combinations(range(9), 3)` looks like

```
(0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,1,4),... (0,1,8),... (0,7,8), (1,2,3),...
```

This gives pair `(0,1)` being part of 7 tuples. Also for all other tuples.

Full wanted output for `range(9), 3`:

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 3, 4)
(0, 5, 6)
(0, 7, 8)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 4, 7)
(1, 5, 8)
(2, 3, 8)
(2, 4, 5)
(2, 6, 7)
(3, 5, 7)
(4, 6, 8)
```

**Building tuples of length `r` given a range of `n` elements uses `(n-1)*n/2` pairs and should provide `(n-1)*n/(r-1)/r` tuples.**

1. How to build the output?
2. How to name this "combinations with pair omitting" thing scientifically?

Comment: according to the formula for(9,3) there should be 18 tuples. 6 missing

Comment: @SmartManoj: No, mind the factorial at the end: (9-1)*9/2/(3-1)! = 8*9/2/3 = 12.

Comment: (9-1)*9/2/(3-1)! = 8*9/2/2 = 18

Comment: (n-1)*n/2/(r-1)! or (n-1)*n/2/(r)

Comment: Yeah, my formular was wrong. I will change the divisor from (r-1)! to (r-1)*r/2.

Answer (score 0):

For tuples of length 3

```
from numpy import roll
from pprint import pprint
def a(s):
    if len(s)<3:return
    s=list(s)
    z=s.pop(0)
    s1,s2=s[0::2],s[1::2]
    l=[]
    for a,b in zip(s1,s2):l+=[(z,a,b)]
    z1,z2=s1.pop(0),s2.pop(0)
    if(len(s1)>1 and len(s2)>1):
        for a,b in sorted(map(sorted,zip(s1,roll(s2,-1)))):l+=[(z1,a,b)]
    if(len(s1)>2 and len(s2)>2):
        for a,b in sorted(map(sorted,zip(s1,roll(s2,1)))):l+=[(z2,a,b)]
    if(len(s1)>3):l+=[a(s1)]
    if(len(s2)>3):l+=[a(s2)]
    return l

s = range(9)
pprint(a(s))
```

Using recursion we could build for various lengths

Comment: Sorry, but the example with range(9) and tuple length of 3 is just for illustration. The intention was to build the result dynamic, for lets say range(81), 9 or range(441), 7.
Btw: in your example the last 2 lines are missing.